# I am getting this error -"RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got 3-D tensor" while running simple RNN using Torch

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, pytorch

1. [**Original Data**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGXqr.jpg)
2. [**Dataset Build**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stkla.jpg)
3. [**Defining Simple RNN Class**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOkRG.jpg)
4. [**Defining forward function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOpBO.jpg)
5. [**Instantiation Of The model**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Tsd.jpg)
6. [**Training The Data Part1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTlOc.jpg)
7. [**Training the data part2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dREWc.jpg)

In the above code snippet mainly training the data part2....I am facing that error. Please help.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make the original data
N = 1000
series  = np.sin(0.1 * np.arange(N))  #+ np.random.randn(N)*0.1  # 
np.random.randn(N)*0.1  is the noise

#plot it
plt.plot(series)
plt.show()

# build the dataset
T = 10  # 10 previous timestamps to predict the next timestamps
X = []
Y = []

# final Target Index: len(series)-1

for t in range(len(series) - T):

  x = series[t:t+T]
  X.append(x)
  y = series[t+T]
  Y.append(y) 

# final t:len(series)-T-1
# if we do range(len(series)-T)

# Final target series = Final t+T
# = Final t+T
# = [len(series)-T-1]+T
# = len(series)-1
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, T)
Y = np.array(Y).reshape(-1, 1) 
N = len(X) 
print("X.shape", X.shape, "Y.shape", Y.shape)

# set device
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)

# define simple RNN
class simpleRNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_hidden, n_rnnlayers, n_outputs):
   super(simpleRNN,self).__init__()
   self.D = n_inputs
   self.M = n_hidden
   self.K = n_outputs
   self.L = n_rnnlayers

# note =  batch_first = True
# applies the convention that our data will be of shape
# num_samples, sequence_length, num_features
# rather than
# sequence_length, num_samples, num_features

   self.rnn = nn.RNN(
    
    input_size = self.D,
    hidden_size = self.M,
    num_layers = self.L,
    nonlinearity = 'relu',
    batch_first = True

)
   self.fc = nn.Linear(self.M, self.K)  
   # size MxK..... final dense layer

  def forward(self, X):
      # initial hidden states
      h0 = torch.zeros(self.L, X.size(0), self.M).to(device) 


      # get RNN unit ouput
      # out is of size (N, T, M)
      # 2nd return value is hidden states at each hidden layer
      # we don't need those now
      out, _ = self.rnn(X, h0) 

      # we only want h(T) at the final time step
      # NxM -> NxK

      out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :]) 
      # going to obtain index RNN output by -1 
      #which gives us back an array of size NxM
      return out

# instantiate the model
model = simpleRNN(n_inputs = 1, n_hidden = 5, n_rnnlayers=1, 
                 n_outputs=1)
model.to(device)

# Loss and Optimizer
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

# make the inputs and targets
X_train = torch.from_numpy(X[:-N//2].astype(np.float32))
Y_train = torch.from_numpy(Y[:-N//2].astype(np.float32))
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X[-N//2:].astype(np.float32))
Y_test = torch.from_numpy(Y[-N//2:].astype(np.float32))

# move data to gpu
X_train, Y_train = X_train.to(device), Y_train.to(device)
X_test, Y_test = X_test.to(device), Y_test.to(device)

# training the data
def full_gd(model,
            criterion,
            optimizer,
            X_train,
            Y_train,
            X_test,
            Y_test,
            epochs=200):

  #stuff to store
  train_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
  test_losses = np.zeros(epochs)
  
  for i in range(epochs):
  # zero the parameter gradient
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  # forward pass
  outputs = model(X_train)
  loss = criterion(outputs, Y_train)

  # backward and optimize
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

  # save the loss
  train_losses[i] = loss.item() # extracting the loss value or 
  #pulling out the loss value using item

  # test_losses
  test_outputs = model(X_test)
  test_loss = criterion(test_outputs, Y_test)
  test_losses[i] = test_loss.item()

  if (i+1) % 5==0:
  print(f"Epoch {i+1}/{epochs}, Train_loss: {loss.item():.4f}, 
  Test_loss: {test_loss.item():.4f}")

  return train_losses, test_losses
```

at this last part while running I am facing the error.

```
train_losses, test_losses = full_gd(model, 
                                criterion,
                                optimizer,
                                X_train,
                                Y_train,
                                X_test,
                                Y_test)
```

The error is that

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
```

last)
 in ()
5                                     Y_train,
6                                     X_test,
----> 7                                     Y_test)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in
forward(self, input, hx)
444                     if hx.dim() != 2:
445                         raise RuntimeError(
--> 446                             f"For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got {hx.dim()}-D tensor")
447                     hx = hx.unsqueeze(1)
448             else:

RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got 3-D tensor

Comment: Share as text all the code and data needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Okay I would share the code as a text

Comment: @ Vitalizzare pls take a look at my problem